# PhpStorm IDE: Cursor gets stuck in text-select (highlight) mode in Ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: ide, phpstorm, mouse, ubuntu-18.04

I am using PhpStorm for working on Laravel projects. However, the mouse gets stuck in text highlight mode and right click does not work on the IDE.
Closing the IDE and restarting does not help solve the issue. I have tried to look for an answer online without success.

Answer (score 6):

For those struggling like me, I got a workaround.

1. I went to my Ubuntu OS "Settings"
2. "Mouse & Settings" option
3. Then "Mouse and TouchPad"
4. Disabled the touchpad by toggling the "ON/OFF" switch
5. Re-enabled the touchpad again by toggling the same "ON/OFF" switch

When I went back to my IDE, behold, it works. My trackpad is no longer stuck in highlight mode.

Disclaimer: I have a touch-sensitive screen and that's how I was able to re-enable the touchpad again. I don't know how one would do this without another input source.

Comment: Thanks!

I tried this but instead of using the touchscreen, I used the keyboard (tab / tab / space etc) to renable the touchpad. That didn't work. Actually touching the screen did work. So I wonder if it's the act of using the touchscreen that does the trick.

Comment: Wow - this is nuts. Thanks for this - it was driving me crazy.

If you're on multiple screens, you may find that it doesn't disappear from all screens. So disable touchpad, disconnect external screens, reconnect and then re-enable the touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

This was a big help for me, thanks!

Just to be clear, enabling/disabling the touchpad is in Ubuntu settings, not in PHPStorm settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this on Dell xpx, Ubuntu 20.04. I had to logout then in for it to go.