# Unusual mouse behavior in PhpStorm on Ubuntu 20

Tags: phpstorm, ubuntu-20.04

I recently switched to a new laptop with Ubuntu 20 and PhpStorm 2021.2.
The PhpStorm editor is enabling/disabling selection mode based on single clicks, rather than click and drag.

The experience is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772484/phpstorm-ide-cursor-gets-stuck-in-text-select-highlight-mode-in-ubuntu-18-lts#new-answer) issue, but disabling Touchpad did not correct.  I do have a touchscreen, but touching the screen does not help.

This does not feel random, but its not logical (to me) either.  The click pattern (in the editor window):

- First click, selection mode
- Second click, still in selection mode
- Third click, selection mode off

While in the editor window, if I move to the top/bottom edge of the editor window, triggering automatic scrolling, selection mode is on.

I don't see this behavior with other applications (e.g. VSCode).

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce it on my setup.
Does it happen in other IDE windows as well? (let's say, a terminal window)

Comment: @duck_in_hat Thanks for reply.  Yes, it happens in the terminal as well.  However, in the terminal, the third click does not release selection mode, its just stuck in selection mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I discovered this issue seems to be related to another application I had installed: Terminator (https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html)

Removing it resolved the issue.

Its odd that this issue only presented with PHPStorm, but I suspect it might present with other Java applications, or applications using the libraries which were in conflict.

Comment: This came back, so I don't think terminator was the cause.  The removal probably just reset something which corrected the issue.  I disabled the touchscreen using xinput disable [xid], described in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766731/i-need-to-permanently-disable-the-touchscreen-input-ubuntu-16-04, but this is not a permanent fix.